# TFS 2015 Build - Run functional tests - Failed to obtain durationInMs field

Tags: selenium, tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, functional-testing

The step "Run functional tests" in a build lauched with TFS 2015 ends with this error message :

```
DistributedTests: Test run is aborted. Logging details of the run logs.
DistributedTests: Une nouvelle série de tests a été créée.
Série de tests mise en file d\'attente pour Project Collection Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION).
DistributedTests: Test discovery started.
DistributedTests: Test Run Discovery Completed . Test run id : 14886
DistributedTests: 2 test cases discovered.
DistributedTests: Test execution started. Test run id : 14886
DistributedTests: UnExpected error occured during test execution. Try again.
DistributedTests: Error : Une ou plusieurs erreurs se sont produites.--->Failed to obtain durationInMs field.
DistributedTests: Test run aborted. Test run id: 14886
```

Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: Please set the system.debug variables to true to build again and if there's more detailed error log? Also find the test run under the test hub page and find if there's some error message? By the way, could you post the log in English

Comment: There are no more details with system.debug = true nor on the test page.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a known issue on [vsts-tasks github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1463), check you are not having the  following:

> System is expected to throw “Failed to obtain durationInMs” error if TFS/Build Agent is Update 1, but Test Agent is higher than Update 1 viz Update 2. The reason is that we have done changes around durationInMs in Test Agent 2015 Update 2 and also in TFS 2015 Update 2, hence Test Agent 2015 Update 2 and higher versions are not backward compatible with lower versions of TFS.

2. Also both from the linked issue and from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/899e20df-4bbe-4262-b245-daa478f341fd/run-functional-test-failed-to-obtain-durationinms-field?forum=tfsbuild) it seems that the reason can be that the system is in French.